# Plumbing terminology. A name for a pipe.

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

So I have this pretty large-size (water) pipe that runs to my house. A couple of years ago I had some guys run a smaller pipe from that "large-size" pipe to my barn. Well, my question is this: what do you call the smaller pipe that splits off the larger pipe and runs to the barn? I know that the first (larger) pipe is called the "main" (if I am not mistaken), but I have totally forgotten what the second (smaller) pipe is called, but I do know that there is a name for it.

Comment: No,  it's some other word. But I do know for sure that there is a word for it out there. I just can't remember it.

Comment: Auxiliary pipe?

Comment: No, not "auxiliary pipe" (even though it totally seems to fit the bill, it's not the word I am looking for) . They called it by some other name ,  I think. I live in North England, by the way. They didn't call it a "service pipe" either...

Comment: Keep these mind, I just found what they called it in the second picture in the link you provided. It's a branch pipe. Thanks a lot. It really bugged me for  a while.

Comment: *main and service lines*; *main and offtake pipes*; Look here: http://city.milwaukee.gov/ImageLibrary/Groups/WaterWorks/files/DiagramofWaterMainandServiceLineMQ.jpg?LargePhoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[United Utilities](http://www.unitedutilities.com/pipes-what-am-i-responsible-for.aspx) seem to call this a 'branch pipe'.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is what the guys who ran that pipe called it...